# How return values when uses json_array where data is array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have my table con one field json, when uses json_array for filter, mysql (5.7) return the filter correctly but I need set an array to json_array for search.

This is sql:

```
select *
from `data` 
where json_contains(model_id->'$[*]', JSON_ARRAY(17) )
```

Return values correctly

[image]

How set an array with more value for the search?

```
select *
from `data` 
where json_contains(model_id->'$[*]', JSON_ARRAY(17, 26) )
```

If uses the query, return empty, I need that return into array values that contains 17 or 26

This is a example with table and query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5DwvtfEhtamnReVMV55XCp/2

Comment: What you're actually looking for is the intersection of the arrays. See the linked question.

Comment: wowww i complicated this.